# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED of socket.io in Angular - Node js

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

In my vps Linux Ubuntu I have a chat that works almost perfectly, it sends and receives messages correctly. Apparently everything works fine, but when I open the console I see errors referring to socket.io. My socket io verion of my backend is "socket.io": "^ 2.1.1", and I use angular 8

> polyfills-es2015.39e6a31b601b9b3913c6.js:1 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NYHZH0I net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The client connects with this line :

> private socket = io.connect('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000');

And on the server I receive it :

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const {database} =require('./keys');
const config=require('./config');
const app =config(express()); 
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var morgan=require('morgan');
var cors=require('cors');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const multer = require('multer');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

console.log(uuidv4());

const path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/uploads'),
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {

        cb(null, uuidv4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}) 
app.use(multer({storage}).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Starting the server
server.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});


app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); // Reconocer el formato JSON 
app.use(cors({origin:['http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080'],credentials:true}));

email = []; 
dsv = [];
creative = [];


mongoose.connect(database.uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(db=>{
    console.log('DB is connected');
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('New connection made!!', socket.id);
    // new user online
      

});
```

As I said before, I am only concerned with that error that appears in the console, because the chat complies with the sending and receiving of messages in real time.
A curious fact is that when I start the server of my local pc the errors stop appearing in the chrome console.
Attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlMrD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14j9h.png)

Comment: I think the problem is that you use the express `listen` method and not the "raw" `http.listen`. Take a look on the socket.io docs: https://socket.io/docs/v2/server-initialization#With-Express Also, socket 2.0 is very old, why you dont use a newer version?

Comment: @Marc I made the changes indicated in the documentation you sent me, and it kept showing the usual error. When updating Socket.io to the most current version, I get a cors error  ** Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NYMnOUo' from origin 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. **

Comment: The error you getting is not the same as  `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`! The cors errors means you cant access the url form where your reqest origins. When your frontend is hosted on port 8080, you cant access any service hosted on port 3000, unless you allow it. Set the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the http service running on port 3000. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @Marc Yes I understood you, but in my code I had already specified to cors that it will only allow requests from the ip address + port, and the data flows. But I don't understand why the new version of socket.io has problems with recognizing the permission that I had already set.

Comment: Why do you set a cors origin for/to "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080" when your node server listens on port 3000 (or vice versa)? You didnt mention your application stack (like is there a nginx or other webserver in front of your app, etc..) that all matters.

Comment: @Marc Sorry I forgot to mention. In port 8080 I have my frontend made in angular 8, running with Nginx in a Docker container. That's why I put that in corsets. All my maintainers work fine, but the maintainer using socket.io has the problem with cors after updating socket.io to the latest version.